# Iframe in a table

Tags: html, iframe, html-table

I am trying to add an iframe in the tbody section of a table. Here is my code so far

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><div>
        <iframe class="tabContent" name="tabIframe2" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            <p>Text</p>
        </iframe>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However, the text does not appear in the iframe. It is below the iframe and within my table. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Tag `iframe` is needed for inserting another HTML page to your one.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Example of using:

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>
```

You can't write any HTML inside `iframe` tag.

Comment: You can write content in iframe using javascript though.

Comment: Wow. Interesting. Thanks, i didnt know that :)

Comment: Can i ask you a question? Why dont you using `ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow || ifrm.contentDocument.document || ifrm.contentDocument;`?

Comment: Out of practice, I like doing this way better because I have faster control over the code if I ever debug.

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe>` is used for embedding a file into another file. In the file where the iframe is, you have to give the source of the page that you want to insert.

Use it like this -
**your file**

```
<tr>
        <td><div>
        <iframe class="tabContent" name="tabIframe2" frameborder="0" src="test.html">
        </iframe>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
```

**file to embed 'test.html'**

```
<p>Text</p>
```